# How to add link on state in jquery when div is being showed. Basically pairing the link and div to display and hide

Tags: jquery, tabs

JS Fiddle Link
http://jsfiddle.net/jshotz/seBeW/4/

The code should turn the link red when it is selected. But only for the one selected. The other links shouldn't turn red. I'm having an issue connecting the link to the div selected. My flow is problem incorrect and there is most likely a better way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Please post more detail than just a link to a jsfiddle. What should this code do? What is it not doing?

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest an alternative to the div id management?  Use an index so you can add anything in the link text.  See here for the example: http://jsfiddle.net/seBeW/5/

IF you still want the index, I included that part commented out (does not work with my extended link however);
Note: I had to "unwrap" your jQuery as you had it, and I put in as domready wrap instead of load, but that is semantics really.

This uses .on() to manage the click event instead of walking the array each time also.
Not fully "pretty" code but it should get you started.

```
var divs = $('#logarea> div');
var alinks = $('#logarea> a');
$(document).on('click', '#logarea> a', function() {
    alinks.removeClass('activeLogAreaLink');
    var this1 = $(this);
    var myindex = alinks.index(this);
    this1.addClass('activeLogAreaLink');
    // convert to lower case
    var thediv = this1.text().toLowerCase();
    $('#debug').text(thediv + myindex);
    divs.hide();
    divs.eq(myindex).show();
    // $('#' + thediv).show();
});
```

Comment: NOTE: the fiddle I posted for example could be improved by: `$('#logarea').on('click', 'a', function() {' for the event management which move from document to just the logarea.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.active { color: red; }
```

JS:

```
$('#logarea a').click(function() {
 // Reset all links to normal color.
 $('#logarea a').removeClass('active');
 // Make this link red. 
 $(this).addClass('active');
});
```